# intelligent rosmake? does rosinstall remove ROS_NOBUILD?

Tags: rosmake, rosinstall

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I'm using ROS on fedora12 in user space, thanks for your help.

1. Calling `rosmake` on a package mostly compiles all needed packages including basics like roscpp again, though they have been built already. Why can't it see that those packages didn't change at all?
2. Therefore I put a `ROS_NOBUILD` in every pkg that needs more than a blink to build. Updating through `rosinstall ~/ros` seems to leave this flag, which prevents the updates from being built. Shouldn't there be an option to do remove the flag if reasonable, or perhaps better a way for rosmake to ignore this flag when called after updating rosinstall?
   Or where am I wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10082/intelligent-rosmake?-does-rosinstall-remove-ros_nobuild?/) by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1650 on 2011-05-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. rosmake simply calls 'make' in all the packages in dependency order.  It will call make, and make will check the dependencies, and determine that nothing needs to be built.
2. ROS_NOBUILD is usually used in read only checkouts such as the ones installed in shared locations.  It states tells the rosmake that someone is managing the tree and to ignore it.  You can use rosmake -i and rosmake -u to mark and unmark.  If you update the tree, you should remove the ROS_NOBUILD flags and then recompile and mark ROS_NOBUILD again.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-05-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) on 2011-05-29**:\

1. Good thought, make needs like a sec to check that nothing needs to be built, which I confirm now from the time stamps. \ 2. It may be nice to have rosmake -i work recursively, or at least stack-inside. Going to try rosprotect now..

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would try out the [rosprotect](http://www.ros.org/wiki/eros_python_tools/rosprotect) tool.

rosinstall generally isn't responsible for building beyond it's own necessary minimal bootstrapping, so it doesn't have these build-related features.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-05-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) on 2011-06-02**:
Thanks for the hint, rosprotect is indeed helpful. There should be an option to protect and never ever (automatically) untprotect a package that downloads more than 3 MB to its build folder and needs like half an hour for that. Maybe I shall make them readonly somehow.